# Facebook update status and tag open graph location

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to update the Facebook status and tag it with open graph place/location

It works fine when i give **place=108424279189115**  (FB id for New York)

curl -X POST  -F 'access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -F 'message=Enjoying Cuilsrl2' https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?**place=108424279189115** -k

but it fails when i give **place=http://www.my-domain.com/f-jospas** (open graph place)

```
Meta Tag:   <meta property="fb:app_id" content="my-id" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:type" content="my-name-space:restaurant" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.my-domain.com/f-jospas" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:title" content="my title" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:image" content="http://my-domain.com/thmb_nail?img_id=ahFzfmthbGx1bWFzdGVyLWhyZHIUCxIIQnVzaW5lc3MiBmpvc3Bhcww&amp;cnt=3" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="place:location:latitude" content="28.5747994643" />
Meta Tag:   <meta property="place:location:longitude" content="77.3710309386" />
```

curl -X POST  -F 'access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -F 'message=Enjoying Curl2' https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?**place=http://www.my-domain.com/f-jospas** -k

**{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}**

Why can't I tag FB status update with opengraph place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open graph places can be used as place tags for open graph actions. They cannot currently be used to tag status updates.

Comment: Thanks Karan,
But the description of the place field is a bit misleading on following URL.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/
I t reads "object containing id and name of Page associated with this location, and a location field containing geographic information such as latitude, longitude, country, and other fields (fields will vary based on geography and availability of information)"